# Barcode reading from RS507 ring scanner with TC55 Bluetooth pairing

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to read barcode from RS507 ring scanner and print the results on my application present on Motorola TC55.  I'm able to pair RS507 Ring scanner to TC55 via Bluetooth connection. But unable to read barcode from RS507. I observed two major problems : 1. RS507 scanner is getting disabled. 2. If I called onClosed() callback method forcefully then scanner is enabled but barcode is still not readable i.e. onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) callback method is not called. Can somebody please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the RS507 and TC55 connected via an SSI Bluetooth connection in order to scan barcodes through the EMDK.  First ensure the RS507 is in SSI mode (instructions are available in https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/rs507-hands-free-imager-product-reference-guide-c-en-us.pdf) and ensure the RS507 is not paired with any other device.  Unpairing can be done through a barcode also available in the reference guide.

Pair the RS507 to the TC55 by scanning the barcode presented by the 'Bluetooth Pairing Utility'

You should be able to use the BarcodeSample1 application from Zebra to test: https://github.com/Zebra/samples-emdkforandroid-6_0/tree/BarcodeSample1.  Choose to scan using the "Bluetooth Scanner" from the dropdown and scanned data from the RS507 should appear in the app.  If that works then you'll know everything is set up successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your help.